# The annotation of polymorphic function

Tags: typescript

community! I need your help with the annotation of the polymorphic function.
I have several types, that have a common key "type" and some other keys:

```js
type T1 = { type: 't1', someKey: number };
type T2 = { type: 't2', anotheKey: string };
type T3 = { type: 't3', andAnotherKey: boolean };
type T = T1 | T2 | T3;
```

and the map of functions. Each key of this map is the "type" field, and the value of the key is a function with an argument of the corresponding type:

```
const TYPE_FN_MAP = {
  t1: (argT1: T1) => argT1.someKey,
  t2: (argT2: T2) => argT2.anotheKey,
  t3: (argT3: T3) => argT3.andAnotherKey,
} as const
```

How to annotate the polymorphic function:

```js
const polymorphicFn = (argT) => TYPE_FN_MAP[argT.type](argT);
```

The main idea is when I need to add a new type, I only extend the TYPE_FN_MAP with a function with an argument of this type, but the function `polymorphicFn` remains unchanged. If I forget the "type" field in a new type, the typescript will show the error in the `polymorphicFn` function.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA3lUkBcUDkw44A0UAzgPYC2EA0hCNgHYCuFARhAE5QC+A3AFAZoMAExJU6cBGx4RRKAEMGZYAAsadbCWAcAlgwDmPAUNgBmcWiEzgZ+UoAmAQWVrOtelFZkyAGwhKxoJSsOLwUAA+sGJRMGYC-ADGZAzasACaAAoAogD6AGIAcrkAsk6ZlvxQ6HDYABQKHAbw2PAAlEgAfIpN8AB05FQehFXoIvWNzePRHYjdk6J9Sirqw6O2E71mrWaz81tLDM6u6hxr3IokUMmpwPxJKWlgfiAUZBxgqrqJ+QziADwwGBQCAAD2AECOVxgnQavVaMDa2AAShBgEwOAwYFJ-kIyAAzDI5ArFMqZADaQPJeCkOAAunTunMiXkiqVyuSFn0hHS4c02gIgA)

Comment: TypeScript can't follow this sort of logic unless the type of `TYPE_FN_MAP` is represented in a particular way. You're basically running into [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the recommended approach is described at [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). If I follow it for your code I get [this version](https://tsplay.dev/N78yqm). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
type ARG_TYPE = typeof TYPE_FN_MAP;

function test<K extends keyof ARG_TYPE>(event: K, ...arg: Parameters<ARG_TYPE[K]>) : ReturnType<ARG_TYPE[K]> {
  // TODO
  return {} as unknown as ReturnType<ARG_TYPE[K]>;
}

test('t1', { type: 't1', someKey: 1 })
```

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA3lUkBcUDkw44A0UAzgPYC2EA0hCNgHYCuFARhAE5QC%20A3AFAZoMAExJU6cBGx4RRKAEMGZYAAsadbCWAcAlgwDmPAUNgBmcWiEzgZ%20UoAmAQWVrOtelFZkyAGwhKxoJSsOLwUAA%20sGJRMGYC-ADGZAzasACaAAoAogD6AGIAcrkAsk6ZlvxQ6HDYABQKHAbw2PAAlEgAfIpN8AB05FQehFXoIvWNzePRHYjdk6J9Sirqw6O2E71mrWaz81tLDM6u6hxr3IokUMmpwPzBkFBOAEoA4rkwWdniQmQAZhkcgVimVMgk-kwGIlgLoUugINoADzUKAQAAewAgRyuAGs6P8nm8Pl9OnUIAA3LHAbDUYh9emTbCZRoKKiYjgkREvd6fHIAbWoAF1Oh1sM8IMAmBwGDApFyibzsgLhahRgB6NWwADyABEtaMOBKpQxUBcFFdITjlAB3E3mqDiyXS2WQeU8r7KzoCbj3THaOp4AjEKxSGxB0iUDSeBDcNpAA)

You may get an error if you didn't provide a valid parameter due to the first parameter such as:

```
test('t1', { someKey: 1 })
// Argument of type '{ someKey: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T1'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type '{ someKey: number; }' but required in type 'T1'.(2345)
```

However, it may be a dupilication if you provide `type` in both every specified type and the key of TYPE_FN_MAP.

It could be simplier as:

```js
type TYPE_FN_MAP = {
  t1: () => { someKey: number },
  t2: (param: boolean) => { anotheKey: string },
  t3: () => { andAnotherKey: boolean },
} 

function test<K extends keyof TYPE_FN_MAP>(event: K, ...arg: Parameters<TYPE_FN_MAP[K]>) : ReturnType<TYPE_FN_MAP[K]> {
  // TODO
  return {} as unknown as ReturnType<TYPE_FN_MAP[K]>;
}

const a = test('t1');
console.log(a.someKey)

test('t2') // Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.(2554)
test('t2', true)
```

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgmgBQKIH0BiA5FBZAggqAXigG8AoKKYARgC4oAKASiID5SoBnAewFsIA0hBD0AdgFdeAIwgAnKAF8ANBSoAmegzABDWdt70p3bgBsI20S0LsSUC92AALQcPqdgsgJaiA5opWUwADMmlY2dqIAJriiDs6yQiJQRqbmov5kClBkZABm4qIAxsCe3OnAEO4APAJQEAAeFVGcUADWwty5sIiomDj4rAwQAG4QosD0AkpQAHRzuj70CLr6EBWynFXwyOhYeAgA2gIAuqws9ABKa%20KyojDgEFs9u-2HJzaqAPSfsADyACK-VSya63UhZbQtAqtWIAd3SkKgV2ANzuDyeOz6%20yOpwA3JkcoUyu47EQqJVgAwAOQ0KlMfFE0Q8MwzEzcHwMbQzHj8RJMHIVdzU4BqOlQb5QJD1SDFCCRKBqOyyHySMbATjTKTiYBQHwOKDUGYMNQAVhNABZ%20YLKTTRdMPOIIPyyEA)